# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting the following error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." and the date format is "DD/MM/YY"

```
    public DataSet GetSynchronizeDataForDLDocs(string date_pushed)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string strQuery=string.Empty;

    if (date_pushed != null && date_pushed != string.Empty)                 // 105
         strQuery = 
            @"select 
                a.DLNO,
                a.NAME,
                b.TOPSTRING,
                Convert(datetime,a.DOB,103) as DOB,
                Convert(datetime,a.DOI,103) as DOI,
                Convert(datetime,b.datepushed,103) as datepushed 
            from 
                PLInfo_Demo a,
                DLInfo_Demo b 
            where 
                a.dlno=b.dlno 
            and
                Convert(DateTime,b.datepushed,103) > CONVERT(varchar,'" + date_pushed + @"' ,103)
            and 
                DATEPART(hh, b.datepushed) > Datepart(hh,'" + date_pushed + @"') 
            and
                DATEPART(MI, b.datepushed) > Datepart(MI,'" + date_pushed + @"' ) 
            and
                DATEPART(ss, b.datepushed) > Datepart(ss,'" + date_pushed + @"' ) 
            order by b.datepushed desc";
    else
         strQuery = @"
            select 
                a.DLNO,
                a.NAME,
                b.TOPSTRING,
                Convert(datetime,a.DOB,103) as DOB,
                Convert(datetime,a.DOI,103) as DOI,
                Convert(datetime,b.datepushed,103) as datepushed 
            from 
                PLInfo_Demo a,
                DLInfo_Demo b
            where 
                a.dlno=b.dlno ";
    ds = DbManager.ExecuteSalarData(
        strQuery, 
        CommandType.Text, 
        DbManager.strcon2, 
        null);

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: What do you think we should do with this mess?

Comment: @Arion this should be better, but I agree -- the OP should not give his "code" to somebody else. It was terribly formatted.

Comment: @Matten : Good that you came around then :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing would be **do not pass in `date_pushed` as a string**. Parse it in your c# (`DateTime.Parse` or similar, perhaps specifying a format and culture), and pass it as a parameter. In all the places you have `'" + date_pushed + '"'`, use `@theParameter` instead.

The next thing is to store `b.datepushed` as a `datetime` - there should be no need to use `convert` on `b.datepushed`. If it is a string **you are doing it wrong**.

After that, you are comparing a `datetime` field to a `datetime` parameter, which will work without issue. For example:

```
and Convert(DateTime,b.datepushed,103) > CONVERT(varchar,'" + date_pushed + @"' ,103)
```

becomes

```
and b.datepushed > @date_pushed
```

where `b.datepushed` is the `datetime` field, and `@date_pushed` is the `datetime` parameter. You can of course use `DATEPART` etc with a `datetime` - the important point is: it isn't parsing anything at all.

Comment: @marc_s After answering one too many questions about date formats - is there that one, canonical answer we can all link to as duplicate? One eg with 400 upvotes so we can avoid arguments in comments?

Answer (score 0):

Some of these must have failed, so please have a look at the actual values:

```
Convert(datetime,a.DOB,103) as DOB,
Convert(datetime,a.DOI,103) as DOI,
Convert(datetime,b.datepushed,103) as datepushed
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use SQL Server.

The valid datetime range in SQL Server is **January 1, 1753** through **December 31, 9999**, as stated on the [datetime (Transact-SQL) MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

I suggest that you watch all your `convert(datetime, ...)` statements for values that fall out of this range.

Comment: Interesting ! seems that's why they had it in varchar fields maybe :)

Comment: @V4Vendetta - probably :). If, for some reason, you need to represent dates outside the range allowed by SQL, then the best way to do this is to parse the dates in C#, as Marc Gravell suggests in his answer.