# he conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Created a table `dbo.CovidStats` with columns `( covidId(int PK), covidDate(datetime), confirmcases(int),Death(int),country(varchar),flag(bit), totalLoss(int) )`

I executed this query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CovidStats VALUES('27/04/2022', 5500, 10, 'USA', 1, 500000);
```

and I got this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
> in an out-of-range value.
>  The statement has been terminated.

when i removed the string from the date i got a Default date of `1900-01-01`. in the column

help please

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `Microsoft sql server management Studio.`

Comment: The fact that you got the error *"A question with that title [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443802/the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out); please be more specific."* should have told you that perhaps you should read that, and that making your title have a typographical error is *not* the way to post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because the system doesn't recognize dd-mm-yyyy as a date format by default.

To solve this you have 2 options:

1. You can use `set dateformat dmy` at the top of your data insert file.
2. But a better approach would be to use yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: Actually a better approach would be to use `yyyyMMdd` format. [Here's why `yyyy-mm-dd` is bad](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7684f7f3c16cb79a4d04de66ea135fa2). Also see [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates) and, specifically, [How SQL Server handles the date format YYYY-MM-DD](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6770/sql-server-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-considerations/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).